# Node.js puppeteer - Fetching desired values not working (td:nth-child(n)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. I tried several attempts but I'm having difficulties getting the 2nd-7th parameter I want.

That's one of my output in the console:

```
Company 1
our error TypeError: formRow.evaluate is not a function
    at main (/home/web/app.js:36:37)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
$ node app.js
```

That's the HTML I'm looking at:

```
<body>
    <table summary="">...</table>
    <table summary="">...</table>
    <div>
        <table summary="">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" align="left">
                        <a href="/count=100">Company 1</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">4</td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/index.htm">[html]</a><a href="/abx.txt">[text]</a></td>
                    <td class="small">Categorie 1<br>Accession Number: 1243689234
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">2018-08-14<br>16:35:41</td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">2018-08-14</td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">
                        <a href="/count=100">001-32722</a><br>181018204
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" align="left">
                        <a href="/count=100">Company 2</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" align="left">
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">4</td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/index.htm">[html]</a><a href="/abx.txt">[text]</a></td>
                    <td class="small">Categorie 2<br>Accession Number: 0001179110
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">2018-08-14<br>16:35:41</td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">2018-08-14</td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">
                        <a href="/count=100">001-32722</a><br>181018204
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ....
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <form>...</form>
    ...
    <table summary="">...</table>
</body>
```

That's my puppeteer setup so far. The first parameter (e.g. Company) is working fine. app.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('some page');

    const table = await page.waitForSelector('body div table[summary]');
    const titles = await page.$$('body div table[summary] tr td[bgcolor]');
    console.log(titles.length);

    const tableRows = await page.$$('body div table[summary] tr[nowrap]');
    console.log(tableRows.length);

  for (let i=0; i < tableRows.length; i++){

    const ciks = await page.$$('body div table[summary] tr td[bgcolor]');
    const cik = ciks[i];
    const button = await cik.$('body div table[summary] tr td[bgcolor] a');
    const titleName = await page.evaluate(button => button.innerText, button);
    console.log(titleName);

    const formRows = await page.$$('body div table[summary] tr[nowrap]');
    const formRow = formRows[i];
    const tableCell = await formRow.$('body div table[summary] tr[nowrap] td');
    const cell = await tableCell.$eval(() => {
      document.querySelector('body div table[summary] tr[nowrap] td:nth-child(1)');
    });
    console.log(cell);
    //const cell = await tableCell.$eval('td', td => td.innerText);
    //console.log(cell);


  }

    console.log('\n');
    console.log('done');
    await browser.close();

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('our error', e);
  }

})();
```

In the above attempt I'm trying to get the 1 and 2 parameter ... but at the end that's the desired Result:

```
Company 1
4
[html]
Categorie 1
2018-08-14 
2018-08-14
001-32722 

Company 2
4
[html]  
Categorie 2
2018-08-14 
2018-08-14
001-32722

...
```

I'm running it on a ubuntu 16.04 32-bit with Chrominium 68 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeatedly assigning values to constants in your `for` loop.

The [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) declaration creates a read-only reference to a value, which means that the variables `ciks`, `cik`, `button`, `titleName`, `formRows`, `formRow`, `tableCell`, and `cell` cannot be reassigned for each iteration of your loop.

This is causing your program to fail after the second iteration.

You should use the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement instead, and you should really declare the variables before the loop.

Take a look at the revised code below:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

( async () =>
{
    try
    {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch( { 'headless' : false } );
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto( 'some page' );

        const table = await page.waitForSelector( 'body div table[summary]' );
        const titles = await page.$$( 'body div table[summary] tr td[bgcolor]' );
        console.log( titles.length );

        const tableRows = await page.$$( 'body div table[summary] tr[nowrap]' );
        console.log( tableRows.length );

        // Declare variables before loop ...

        const ciks = await page.$$( 'body div table[summary] tr td[bgcolor]' );
        const titleName = await page.evaluate( button => button.innerText, button );
        const formRows = await page.$$( 'body div table[summary] tr[nowrap]' );
        const cell = await page.$( 'body div table[summary] tr[nowrap] td:nth-child(1)' );

        let cik;
        let button;
        let formRow;
        let tableCell;

        for ( let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++ )
        {
            cik = ciks[i];

            button = await cik.$( 'body div table[summary] tr td[bgcolor] a' );

            console.log( titleName );

            formRow = formRows[i];

            tableCell = await formRow.$( 'body div table[summary] tr[nowrap] td' );

            console.log( cell );
        }

        console.log( '\n' );
        console.log( 'done' );

        await browser.close();
    }

    catch ( e )
    {
        console.log( 'our error', e );
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. By any chance ... could you also provide some code ?